# XSL: How do I get the two nodes to show up side by side?

Tags: xml, xslt

This stylesheet shows all the Product_Name data first, then it shows all the Product_Image_File second.  How can I format it so it shows first the Product_Name followed by a | and the Product_Image_File followed by a br

EXAMPLE OF WHAT I NEED IT TO SPIT OUT:

```
Product_Name|Product_Image_File</br>
```

CURRENT XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="products/product/Product_Name" />
    <xsl:value-of select="products/product/Product_Images[1]/item[1]/Product_Image_File[1]" />
</xsl:template>
```

The new above XSL works but stops after printing out the first product.

Comment: You should use concat() function.

Comment: Add the `|` at the end of the Product_Name template. Or better `<xsl:text>|</xsl:text>`

Comment: Didn't work. What I don't understand is why the Product_Name template goes through all the product names first... Then goes through all the product_image_file template second.    ... I simply want the product_name to get printed followed by the product_image_file, then it goes to the next product and starts this again.  I wish there was a program or online tool where I just select how I want the XML to show in an easy to use interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using union (`|`) in the `xsl:apply-templates`...

**XML Input** (guess based on paths in xslt and previous question)

```
<products>
    <product>
        <Product_Name>Product A</Product_Name>
        <Product_Images>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/this_d_one1.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/testNOTHISONE.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
        </Product_Images>
    </product>
    <product>
        <Product_Name>Product B</Product_Name>
        <Product_Images>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/this_d_one33.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
            <item>
                <Product_Image_File>hello/testNOTHISONE3.jpg</Product_Image_File>
            </item>
        </Product_Images>
    </product>
</products>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="product/Product_Name|product/Product_Images[1]/item[1]/Product_Image_File[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product_Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product_Image_File">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (raw)

```
Product A|hello/this_d_one1.jpg<br>Product B|hello/this_d_one33.jpg<br>
```

**Output** (rendered)

Product A|hello/this_d_one1.jpg
Product B|hello/this_d_one33.jpg